# Android: access a drawable from a specific -dpi folder?

Tags: android, resources, drawable

I have two drawable folders: drawable-mdpi and drawable-ldpi

I want to keep this structure (i.e. I don't' want to move my images to /assets), so that Android will automatically pick the appropriate artwork depending on the device density, however, on occasion I need to access the larger drawable version on the smaller device.

Is there a way to access the drawable-ldpi folder from code? I thought the following might be the answer, but it did not work:

```
    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.test/res/drawable-ldpi/icon");
    imageview.setImageURI(path); //assume imageview is already initialized etc.
```

I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException (no such file or directory) warning (it doesn't crash, but it just doesn't load either).

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: No, it's not reachable the way you need.

Comment: So my best bet is to load all my images into the assets folder, and instead of using androids built in detection, to manually detect the screen density, and load the corresponding images. Way more annoying, but at least I can then access the hdpi versions as needed?

Answer (score 2):

probably not much help but there is Resources.getDrawableForDensity() but this is for API 15 :-(

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you ever need to use the HDPI version, keep ONLY the HDPI version of the image, and the lower density phone will automatically use the HDPI drawable because it has no choice (i.e. a lower resolution image with that drawable name does not exist).

If you really need to switch between the hdpi and mdpi version I would suggest using a different filename and swapping programmatically, or showing/hiding XML elements if you prefer doing it that way... but that seems a little heavy-handed.

Comment: I really need to use the mdpi, as I am loading many images, and using the hdpi causes VM OOM error.

Comment: In what situation would you like to use the HDPI image, then? Why not simply have two drawables and swap them in the situation where you need to use the mdpi?

Comment: I want to load up the screen with the smaller images. When an image is selected, I want to display the larger version of that image. If I load the hdpi versions and have them scale down to fit the smaller screen, I get OOM errors.

Comment: How about, when the image is selected, you load up the HDPI version of that image? This can be done by naming the mdpi drawable pic_mdpi.png and the hdpi pic_hdpi.png and then when the user selects the image, programmatically set the background resource or source of the view (depending on the type of View) to the pic_hdpi drawable.

Comment: Right, but that will prevent me from having Android automatically detect the device dpi and loading the appropriate drawable. It sounds like I have to handle all of this manually.

Comment: True, but you said you couldn't handle the HDPI images anyway due to OOM errors... the foundation of your question is attempting to access the HDPI folder programmatically, so at that point you might as well have different filenames. Does this mean that on HDPI devices you *aren't* getting OOM errors?

Answer (score -1):

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.abc);
image.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Try reading [THIS LINK](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/practices/screens_support.html) also for more study over hdpi and mdpi concept

Comment: This will use the system's normal resource resolution and so will not give you the larger image.